# Progress bar prints unwanted characters to the console

Tags: python, terminal, progress-bar, stdout, ansi-escape

I know that the subject sounds rather vague, I'll try my best to explain.

I'm new and I'm trying to make a custom progress bar with the help of progressbar2 lib. My OS is Windows 10, my terminal is the standard command line and I'm using Python 3.8.1.

I took an example of the filling animated progress bar from the official docs and tried to modify it a bit to make it colorful using ANSI escape characters. Here is my code:

```
    """
    Displays a fancy progress bar.

    :param text: Progress bar text
    :return: Progress bar object
    """
    V = '\033[38;5;31m'
    END = '\033[0m'
    bar = \
        progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[f'{V}{text}{END}', progressbar.Percentage(),
        progressbar.Bar(marker=progressbar.AnimatedMarker(fill=f'{V}#{END}'))])
    return bar
```

But when I do that, I observe a weird side-effect. I took a short screencast to make it easier to understand: https://youtu.be/p_YpkbJrTa8

At **0:05** you can see that the cursor leaves a few blue `|` characters in the console when updating the bar and the animation after the hash sign is bugged. However, if I keep the hash sign colorless, everything looks just fine (see **0:35**).

You can also see, that in the first case the cursor jumps to the hast sign every time it updates and in the second case it stays at the rightmost position.

So, is there a way to fix that, so that the hash sign stays colorful and animated, but there are no unwanted `|` characters in the console?

I would appreciate any help.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to kinda fix that, wrapping the markers which constitute the animation with the same ANSI color codes.

```
   V = '\033[38;5;31m'
   END = '\033[0m'
   bar = \
        progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[f'{V}{text}{END}', progressbar.Percentage(),
        progressbar.Bar(marker=progressbar.AnimatedMarker(markers=f'{V}|/-\\{END}', 
                                                          fill=f'{V}#{END}'))])
    return bar
```

Now the `|` character stays at the rightmost position, where it belongs, but the animation is still kind of broken. I made another screencast to demonstrate that: https://youtu.be/t2YwlBQxcN0

Looks like the hyphen character is missing and sometimes the animated marker becomes colorless (see **0:09** and especially **0:21**). I'll try to file an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

There's some other possibilities, but looking at the source for progressbar2, I see a mismatch between its code and your example, referring to this line:

```
progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[f'{V}{text}{END}', progressbar.Percentage(),
```

In [`no_color`](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar/blob/04d0f650ca0be9fb1cb3097b01d5e39ceb335f62/progressbar/utils.py#L83), it matches this pattern to the values given:

```
pattern = '\\\u001b\\[.*?[@-~]'
```

That would be a problem with your example, which uses two occurrences of an escape sequence (and would make it miscompute the length of the printable part of the string).

I'd expect something less greedy, e.g.,

```
pattern = '\\\u001b\\[[0-9;:]*[@-~]'
```

so that the final character of the sequence would follow an optional parameter list, rather than just anything (including other escape sequences).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm not quite sure that I totally understand your answer, but I tried to test the original pattern against the one you have suggested, and it seems like it makes no difference. Both patterns completely delete all ANSI escape sequences from my fill string, leaving only one fill character `#` (which seems to me like a correct behavior). Nevertheless, I tried to edit the source code itself and run my script. The bug stays. 

What are the other possibilities you've mentioned?

Comment: I was able to partially fix it. I made an update to the question and filed an issue on GitHub.